# Broken border around textbox in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, virtualbox

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omtttLqn/1/)

```
input {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

It looks good in any browsers other than IE 11.

If you test it in IE11 you'll see that the border is broken (white pixels) at the beginning (top and bottom) just after rounded corners, like this:

[image: ie11]

What do I miss in my style declaration?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE11...

Comment: mmm that's strange... I'm on Windows 8.1 running on VirtualBox. Could it be a VirtualBox video card driver bug?

Comment: Could be, although I'm on Windows 7 here, so it could be a Windows version difference. VirtualBox error seems quite likely, though.

Comment: @lviggiani quite possibly. It works okay for me as well (using Windows 8.1 not running VirtualBox).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbso: thank'you guys for testing it for me on native Windows installation. So, I trust you guys! :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: thank'you guys for testing it for me on native Windows installation. So, I trust you guys! :)

Comment: FYI - I've just tested IE11 on every OS which will run it in BrowserStack... I'm unable to reproduce what you are showing in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to replicate this issue in IE 11 inside virtual box. It works correctly in Edge.

**This is the only solution I could find to fix this issue:**

Go to device manager and disable the default Virtual box display adaptor.